# Find $\lim_{x\to 0^+}(\sin x)^\frac{1}{\ln x}$

Tags: calculus

$\lim_{x\to 0^+}(\sin x)^\frac{1}{\ln x}$

I was trying to change it to $\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{(\sin x)^\frac{1}{\ln x}}{x^\frac{1}{\ln x}}{x^\frac{1}{\ln x}}$, but I don't know what to do next.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: use the exponential form! $\sin(x)^{1/\ln(x)}=\exp\left(\dfrac{\ln(\sin x)}{\ln(x)}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use an amusing approach.

First of all, exponentialize it as:

$$(sin(x))^{1/\ln(x)} = \large e^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}\ln(\sin(x))}$$

Then multiply and divide for $x$ inside the Sine:

$$\large e^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}\ln(\sin(x)\frac{x}{x})}$$

Now the well known limit $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ goes to $1$, hence you're left with

$$\large e^{\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(x)}}$$

Which is $$\boxed{e}$$

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Basic analysis:I am approximating a function up to the $n$-th order

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf When you use Taylor Series, you're taking a function $f(x)$ and you're expanding it in a polynomial of order $n$. Clearly the function $f$ needs to be infinitely differentiable, and then when you use Taylor Series you can go on and on and on. But the most of the times you just need $2$ terms, or $2$ at most, hence you write the BIG O notation just because you're finicky :D describe the error term in an approximation to a mathematical function. The most significant terms are written explicitly, and then the least-significant terms are summarized in a single big O term.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf For example, take $e^x$, which you know has a Taylor Series like $1 + x + \frac{1}{2}x^2 + O(x^3$). It means the absolute-value of the error $e^x − (1 + x + x^2/2)$ is at most some constant times $|x^3|$ when $x$ is close enough to $0$.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Aye, I went through an oversight. Corrected and changed.

Comment: That's much better now `:)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thank you for having made me to notice the obscenity I wrote :D